# PHP / MySQL - foreach loop $_POST inserting into database not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic form that can add and remove `textarea` elements. I'm trying to get these elements inserted into a MySQL database with a `for` loop.

```
<?php 

//if upload button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    //connect to the database
    $db = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (paragraph) VALUES ('$paragraph')";

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST as $value){
        $paragraph = $_POST['paragraph'][$i];
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $i++;
    }

    header("location: form.php");
    exit;

}

?>

<html>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="form.php">

        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" id="upload">

    </form>

    <button onclick="addParagraph()">Add Paragraph</button>



</body>
</html>

<script>

//add paragraph div
function addParagraph() {
    $("form").append('<div><textarea name="paragraph[]"></textarea><button class="remove">Remove</button></div>');
}

//remove paragraph div
$(document).on('click', ".remove", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});



</script>
```

Unfortunately, this seems to enter empty fields into the database. I believe the problem occurs in the `foreach` loop within the php code.

Comment: Learn about prepared statemrnts to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original sql sort of looks like an attempt at using `prepared statements` - but was vulnerable to sql injection - you should be able to do something like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['upload']) ) {

    //connect to the database
    $db = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table ( paragraph ) VALUES ( ? )";
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);

    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param('s',$paragraph);

        foreach ( $_POST['paragraph'] as $paragraph){
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    exit( header("location: form.php") );
}
```

Comment: Coming back to this, what is this the significance of the `?` in the SQL statement? Is it a placeholder?

Comment: Yes - the variables are bund to those placeholders using ( in mysqli ) `bind_param` or, in PDO, `bindParam` - it means that the interpretation of the values is done by the db itself. Another major benefit of prepared statements comes when inserting values in a loop for instance. The statement is prepared once outside the loop, the binding happens outside the loop but inside the loop you assign new values to the variables and then execute

Answer (score 1):

You assign the value of `$paragarph` to the SQL Statement in this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (paragraph) VALUES ('$paragraph')";
```

Here the value is empty, that's why it is empty in your database.

You have to put the statement in your loop:

```
 foreach ($_POST['paragraph'] as $value){
        $paragraph = value[$i];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (paragraph) VALUES ('$paragraph')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $i++;
    }
```

As i suggested in my comment:

Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Should loop through `$_POST['paragraph']` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: I tried to use mysqli_real_escape_string earlier, and I was getting an error that I wasn't providing two variables. I'll have to look further into this. That would prevent SQL injection, right?

Comment: @coffeebot: No `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not save against SQL injection